# React-native TypeError:'nativeInterface.configure

Tags: react-native

Am trying to build a `react-native` app after building am try to login with existing `username` and `password` when i click login button its show

> TypeError:'nativeInterface.configure' can someone help me please.

[image: image here]

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Please read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: which code i have to post android/build-gradle or app/build-gradle

Comment: React native code